# What is the difference between a crud controller and a DAO?

Tags: java, mysql, crud, dao

I have received an assigned with some empty skeleton files. Amongst these files there's two interfaces which I can't seem to understand. This one:

```
/*
 * Interface defining abstract CRUD methods for each of your Controllers.
 */
public interface CrudController<T> {

List<T> readAll();

T readyById();

T create();

T update();

int delete(); 
}
```

and this one:

```
/*
 * Interface defining abstract CRUD methods for each of your Data Access Objects.
 * Implementation of this will involve JDBC.
 */
public interface DAO<T> {

List<T> readAll();

T readById(Long id);

T readLatest();

T create(T t);

T update(T t);

int delete(Long id);

T modelFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException;
}
```

What I don't understand is why there is a need for both of these. The work is supposed to be related to managing a mySql schema using Java. What is the difference between a CrudController and a DAO class, I though both of these were used for Database persistence and reading.

Comment: Based on your interface code, a CRUDController gets its inputs from class fields, while a DAO gets its inputs from method parameters.  Otherwise, both classes get information from a database.  I'm not sure what the modelFromResultSet method is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally the separation exist to separate interactions with the database/persistence and business logic. The difference between the two in this case is the CrudController would handle the business/application logic and the dao would handle the persistence logic. For example, in the scope of a REST application, the controller is receiving the request and calling a implementation of the dao (or a service which calls the dao) to perform database actions.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the DAO design pattern we separate the part that communicates with the database from the rest of the application.

The DAO pattern defines the CRUD (create,read,update,delete) operations for all the entities. We can completely separate the persistence layer by adding named/native queries. These will be used for the entity itself.

```
public interface DAO<T,E extends Serializable>{
  public T save(T object);
  public Boolean delete(T object);
  public T update(T object);
  public T find(E id);
}
```

The interface for the DAO defines only the operations specified in the implementation.

**So CRUD just an abbreviation but DAO is a design pattern.**

[LINK](https://culture.singular.uk/java-design-patterns-part-1/#:%7E:text=The%20DAO%20pattern%20defines%20the,used%20for%20the%20entity%20itself.&text=The%20interface%20for%20the%20DAO,operations%20specified%20in%20the%20implementation.)